# Kafka: Consumers adding multiple records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have three consumers all with multiple instances which all are consuming the same topic. I want each consumer to consume the topic once. To do this I have created a consumer group. From what I read Kafka should be smart enough to select one instance of a service to consume the topic but this is not happening and all instances of all consumers are consuming the topic

I thought it might have been something to do with the three consumers all having the same group name so I turned off two of the consumers leaving one consumer with two instances but I still see two records going into the database when the consumer group should only be selecting one instance to insert into the database.

Am I doing something wrong or missing something below?

Application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input-data:
          destination: publisheddata.t    
          group: publisheddata
      kafka:
    bindings:         
      input: 
        consumer:
           autoCommitOffset: false                
    binder:
      auto-create-topics: true
      kafka:
        mode: raw
spring:
    cloud:
      stream:
        kafka:
          binder:
            brokers: kafka:9092
            zk-nodes: kafka:2181
```

Channels.java

```
public interface Channels {

  String INPUT_DATA = "input-data";

  @Input(INPUT_DATA)
  SubscribableChannel dataInput();
}
```

DataHandler.java

```
@EnableBinding(Channels.class)
@Configuration
public class DataMessageHandler {

@StreamListener(Channels.INPUT_DATA)
public void handle(Message<?> message) {
  ... handling message ...
}
```

Comment: how many partitions have you got on the topic?

Comment: there are no partitions setup on the topic

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone runs into this issue in future, after looking into this for a few days I found out the issue was with the Spring Cloud version I was using I was using `Brixton.RELEASE`, once I updated this to `Dalston.SR2` this solved my issues